# javascript - window.onload not working

Tags: javascript

**HTML:**

```
<h1 id="id"></h1>
Hello!
```

**JS:**

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "Hello world!";  
};
```

The above code is meant to set the innerHTML of the element with ID "id" to "Hello world!". But it does not work.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chris97ong/f3DpG/1/).
Why is this so?

Comment: The fiddle works, IF you set the javascript to be in the <head> section. If this whole code starts when the page is loaded, it's too late. So, where did you put this code in your page?

Comment: I put it in the `<body>` section. I see why now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have told JSFiddle to assign the `onload` event handler when the `onload` event fires.

Since the event doesn't fire a second time, the function never runs.

Change the "where to put the JS" option and [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/f3DpG/2/).

Comment: @quentin I dont get this answer? Could you please explain this more? I did not see any difference between two JSFiddle :(

Answer (score 1):

I guess according to your code the inner html will be replaced by "Hello World" and its working as it should be as shown below ..I guess some problem with your jsfiddle setting like select `"No wrap - in <head>"` in the second dropdown.

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "Hello world!";  
};
```

Demo :- http://jsfiddle.net/Rqe6K/3/